# Codeigniter save selected language in session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter application the default language is english and I have tow anchor to switch language to english.

The problem is when I switch language from `english` to `eg:arabic` the same page is changing but when I go to another page it is back to english again.

MY_Lang.php

```html
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

// Add your languages here
private $languages = array(
'en' => 'english',
'ar' => 'arabic'
);

// special URIs (not localized)
    private $special = array (
'admin',
'assets',
'editor'
);

// where to redirect if no language in URI
private $uri;
private $default_uri;
private $lang_code;

/**************************************************/

function MY_Lang()
{
    parent::__construct();

    global $CFG;
    global $URI;
    global $RTR;

    $this->uri = $URI->uri_string();
    $this->default_uri = $RTR->default_controller;

    $uri_segment = $this->get_uri_lang($this->uri);
    $this->lang_code = $uri_segment['lang'] ;

    $url_ok = false;
    if ((!empty($this->lang_code)) && (array_key_exists($this->lang_code, $this->languages)))
    {
        $language = $this->languages[$this->lang_code];
        $CFG->set_item('language', $language);
        $url_ok = true;
    }

    if ((!$url_ok) && (!$this->is_special($uri_segment['parts'][0]))) // special URI -> no redirect
    {
        // set default language
        $CFG->set_item('language', $this->languages[$this->default_lang()]);

        $uri = (!empty($this->uri)) ? $this->uri: $this->default_uri;
        $uri = ($uri[0] != '/') ? '/'.$uri : $uri;
        $new_url = $CFG->config['base_url'].$this->default_lang().$uri;

        header("Location: " . $new_url, TRUE, 302);
        exit;
    }
}
```

and view.php

```html
<div class="lang-bar pull-left">
<a href="<?php echo site_url($this->lang->switch_uri('ar'));?>" class="btn btn-success">Ar</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url($this->lang->switch_uri('en'));?>" class="btn btn-success">En</a>
</div>
```

so how keep the language until close page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the library works, but maybe you don't load session library to keep language values accross pages. Here's another lib I like to use: https://github.com/devtime-share/codeigniter-kitlang

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to save the selected language in the database and then later retrieve it rather than using sessions. I also have the same situation as you are trying to figure out how to change the language, but I am using database instead of sessions..